# MySQL : ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, ddl

I'm running in this error when trying to forward engineer my ERD in MySQLWorkbench:

Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:

```
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`Order`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Order` (
          `idOrder` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Klantnummer` INT NOT NULL,
          `Bezorger1` INT NOT NULL,
          `idTreinbezorger` INT NULL,
          `Bezorger2` INT NULL,
          `Kluiscode` INT NULL,
          `Starttijd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
          `Eindtijd` DATETIME NULL,
          `OphaalAdres` INT NOT NULL,
          `AfleverAdres` INT NOT NULL,
          `idOrderStatus` INT NOT NULL,
          `VerwachteEindtijd` DATETIME NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idOrder`),
          INDEX `fk_Order_OrderStatus1_idx` (`idOrderStatus` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_Order_Treinbezorger1_idx` (`idTreinbezorger` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_Order_Adres1_idx` (`OphaalAdres` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_Order_Adres2_idx` (`AfleverAdres` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_Order_Bezorger1_idx` (`Bezorger2` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_OrderStatus1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`idOrderStatus`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`OrderStatus` (`idOrderStatus`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_Treinbezorger1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`idTreinbezorger`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Treinbezorger` (`idTreinbezorger`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_Adres1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`OphaalAdres`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Adres` (`idAdres`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_Adres2`
            FOREIGN KEY (`AfleverAdres`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Adres` (`idAdres`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_Bezorger1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`Bezorger2`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Bezorger` (`idBezorger`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_Order_Account1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`idOrder`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`Account` (`idOrder`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 11 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

I've read that I had to make all the columns that I linked need to be the same datatype. I checked them all and they all match (all being INT).

Question is, what am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure , all the referenced columns are of  INT type and all the referenced columns of referenced_table are defined as PRIMARY KEY. ??